# vb.net to c# of ChrW(Keys.Back)

Tags: c#, vb.net

Good day guys, can anyone help me to convert this code ChrW(Keys.Back) from vb.net to c#. I have this line of code in my vb project

```
If Not IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) And e.KeyChar <> ChrW(Keys.Back) Then
        e.Handled = True
End If
```

Thanks

Comment: SO should provide a feature to do multiple downvotes (same user) for exceptional cases.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if ((!IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar != ((char)(Keys.Back))))) {
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: I've already tried that... but it wont work but thanks for the help, appreciate it.

Comment: This is straight translation of VB code to C#. Can you make sure, if your VB code itself is working?

Comment: have some changes, but i think this will do. thank you.

Comment: 1. It's not a straight or good translation - there's no 'IsNumeric' global in C#.  2. That's a few too many parentheses pairs, don't you think?

Comment: I change IsNumeric to char.IsNumber, if you have other suggestion I'm open about it

Comment: @DaveDoknjas You are correct. My mistake. Got lazy to cross-check code. I guess you downvoted for that reason. Had I been in your place I would rather edit the answer itself or suggest it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!Information.IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) & e.KeyChar != Strings.ChrW(Keys.Back))      {
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Try that maybe?

Comment: A good translation shouldn't be so dependent on the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly.